# Auto save on a textarea takes too long

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

On `Google Documents`, there is no a `SAVE` button. All changes are automatically saved by typing a document.

It takes about 2 seconds between the message `Saving...` and `Saved`, if two words (`lorem ipsum`) are typed.

Trying to create the same funcionality on my own site.
A textarea id `tx` has an input event:

```
$('#tx').on('input', function(){
    console.log('Saving...');   
    let story = $(this).val();
    $.post('index-pro.php', {fn: 'update', args: [story]}, function(){
        console.log('Saved');
    });
});
```

**index-pro.php**

```
function update($story){
    global $db;
    $sql = "update arts set story = :astory";
    $st = $db->prepare($sql);
    $st->execute([
        ":astory" => $story
    ]);
}
```

It always takes about 5 seconds between two `console.log`.

What is the reason and is it possible to get 2 seconds, as on `Google Drive`?

And more - the distance between my comp and my hosting server is about 3 km.

The distance between my comp and a Google server is much, much more.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this on `input` means every keystroke results in a save. If I type five hundred characters, that's five hundred AJAX calls. They'll start to pile up and fail.

Consider "debouncing" your AJAX calls, so they don't fire for every single keystroke. Lodash has a [really good debounce function](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce) that's widely used.

Comment: Thanks, very useful for me, but... I have the same 5 seconds typing just one single letter, without a chance for bouncing.

Comment: Then you need to start looking for the bottleneck. Take a look at the requests in your browser's network panel's timing section. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#timing See if your server's load is high. See if the database has a bunch of long-running queries. Use something like Xdebug or Blackfire to profile the PHP side of things. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: google probably spends more money on servers and optimizing performance than you do.

Comment: @dandavis Five seconds is quite a slow request, though.